# Angular 4 built for production but browser does not initiate HTTP requests for *.bundle.js

Tags: angular

The following is the workflow:

1. Angular 4 with Material Design app built as `ng build --prod`
2. Copying `/dist` to `/www` wherein, all files in www are marked as `EmbeddedResource` to serve the files through `.NET` `HttpListener` based in-process web sever
3. When Chrome loads `http://localhost:5000/index.html`, `HttpListener` responds with `index.html` from `/www`.
4. After the above, Chrome does not issue any further requests and Chrome just shows `Loading...` from the `<app-root>Loading...</app-root>`.

The question: What would cause the Chrome not send out any requests after loading `index.html`? It works fine through `ng serve`

Comment: did you check your developers network tab/console for any errors?

Comment: No errors in Chrome Developer Console..Chrome simply seems to be not initiating any request to the server having loaded `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Post the errors you get in the browser console. Maybe it's the base element in the index which has to be in the `<head>` node.

```
<base href=".">
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

Chrome was indeed sending out requests..Developer Console > Network tab showed it... (all requests pending, except index.html)

The problem was I forgot to process HTTP requests in a loop..!! My bad...!

Anyways, many thanks for comments and answers.